# How can i override refinerycms-search views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms, refinery

I want to customize the display of the search results but I cannot seem to override refinerycms-search views?  I have looked at https://gist.github.com/ryandeussing/2502881 and have tried a combination of rake task, but no success.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just adding the files manually and copying pasting the code from github. For example,
I created a directory and a file app/views/refinery/**search/show.html.erb** and copied and paste the code from refinerycms-search corresponding views as a starting point.